# Error al tratar de realizar operacion con &

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un programa para leer 2 string (direcciones) que ingresa el usuario para luego aplicar el operador `&` y así obtener una nueva dirección.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa `172.217.0.164` y luego `255.255.0.0`, el resultado al aplicar el operador `&` entre las dos direcciones, seria `172.217.0.0`. Lo cual es lo que pretendo obtener a la hora de realizar la operación en `C`.

El problema es que me sale el siguiente error:

> [Error] invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'char *')

- El código en `C`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char *direccion;
    char *mascara;
    direccion = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    mascara = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

    printf("Introduce la primera direccion ip: ");
    scanf("%s", direccion);

    printf("Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: ");
    scanf("%s", mascara);

    /*aplicar bit a bit con el operador &*/
    char *n;

    n = direccion & mascara;

    printf("La nueva direccion es la siguiente %s", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estás aplicando `&` a los punteros, en lugar de hacerlo a los valores apuntados. Es decir, debería ser `*direccion & *mascara`. Naturalmente eso haría la operación sólo entre 1 char (el primero) de la dirección y de la máscara. Para que lo haga con todos, debes iterar en un bucle. Y los resultados ir guardándolos en otra zona que tenga espacio también para 16 char (por tanto necesitas también un `calloc()` para el puntero `n`). Y en todo caso, temo que esto no hará lo que buscas, pues el `&` se hará entre los códigos ascii de los caracteres, aunque no está claro qué buscas.

Comment: @abulafia ya modifico para aclarar lo que busco

Comment: Lo que me temía. Hay mucha tela que cortar aqui. He escrito una respuesta un tanto larga tratando de explicarlo todo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay varios conceptos erróneos en tu planteamiento:

### No puedes hacer `&` entre punteros

La operación `&` realiza un AND lógico entre los *bits* de los datos que le pases. Por ejemplo, si le pasas como datos (a la izquierda y a la derecha del operador `&`) los números 7 y 12, que en binario son `00000111` y `00001100` respectivamente, entonces el resultado será `00000100`, es decir, 4, pues se ha hecho la operación:

```
      00000111
  AND 00001100
  -------------
      00000100
```

El resultado sólo tiene 1 donde ambos datos tengan 1.

En tu código haces `direccion & mascara`, pero `direccion` y `mascara` son punteros. Un puntero es un número que representa una dirección de memoria (en este caso la dirección donde están las cadenas). Si el compilador te hubiera dejado usar esta instrucción, tendrías como resultado otro número binario que sería el AND entre los bits de ambos punteros. Esto no tiene sentido, y el compilador no te deja hacerlo.

El enfoque correcto sería recorrer en bucle los bytes apuntados por `direccion` y a la vez los apuntados por `mascara` y para cada uno de ellos hacer un AND, y guardar el resultado en direcciones apuntadas por `n`. Algo como lo siguiente:

> Nota: Esto sigue estando mal por lo que explicaré después

```
int main(){
    char *direccion;
    char *mascara;
    direccion = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    mascara = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

    printf("Introduce la primera direccion ip: ");
    scanf("%s", direccion);

    printf("Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: ");
    scanf("%s", mascara);

    /*aplicar bit a bit con el operador &*/
    char *resultado;

    resultado = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
      resultado[i] = direccion[i] & mascara[i];
    }
    printf("La nueva direccion es la siguiente %s\n", resultado);
}
```

Ahora bien, ejecuta esto y obtendrás la siguiente sorpresa:

```
Introduce la primera direccion ip: 172.217.0.164
Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: 255.255.0.0
La nueva direccion es la siguiente 050.215.0.0
```

¿Qué ha pasado?

### Estás haciendo `&` entre los códigos ASCII

Efectivamente, el dato al que apunta `direccion` es el carácter `'1'` (el primer carácter de la cadena introducida por el usuario), y el dato a que apunta `mascara` es el carácter `'2'`. Cuando hagas la operación `&` entre ellos, no estarás haciéndola entre 1 y 2, sino entre el código ASCII del '1' y el código ASCII del '2', pues eso es lo que almacenan las cadenas.

El código ASCII del '1' es 00110001 (49) y el del '2' es 00110010 (50). Si haces el AND bit a bit entre esas cantidades obtienes `00110000` (48). ¡Y resulta que ese es el código ASCII del cero! Por eso el resultado tiene un 0 como primer carácter.

Y así puedes ir viendo tú todos los demás. Nota curiosa, el punto se respeta porque los grupos de cifras tienen la misma longitud en la dirección y en la máscara, por eso llega un momento en que tiene que hacer el `&` entre el código ASCII de un  `'.'` y el código ASCII de otro `'.'`, lo que le da obviamente como resultado el código ASCII de otro `'.'`

No obstante no es esto lo que se buscaba. Todo está mal planteado debido a que...

### Una IP no es una cadena

Pero es que aunque no estuvieran involucrados los códigos ASCII seguiría estando mal, pues una dirección IP es en realidad **un dato de 32 bits**, y cuando la escribes en la forma `"172.217.0.164"`, eso no es más que un truco para que nos sea más sencillo de recordar o teclear.

En esa cadena estás representando en realidad **cuatro bytes**. La IP es en realidad un número binario de 32 bits que sale de concatenar la representación binaria de cada uno de esos 4 bytes. En este caso seria:

```
10101100 11011001 00000000 10100100
  172      217       0        164
```

Es decir, la IP es el número `10101100110110010000000010100100` que en decimal sería el 2899902628. Esa es la IP y la notación de puntos sólo es una forma más fácil de escribirla.

Sólo teniendo las IPs como números binarios de 32 bits tiene sentido hacer `&` entre ese número y la máscara (que por cierto sería `11111111111111110000000000000000`). La representación como cadena separada por puntos no nos sirve.

### Cómo hacerlo bien

Necesitas convertir la cadena introducida por el usuario (que usa la notación de puntos) a un número de 32 bits, tanto para la dirección como para la máscara. Esa conversión no es trivial. Hay que detectar donde están los puntos, separar por ellos, convertir cada subcadena resultante en un entero de 8 bits, y luego concatenar esos cuatro enteros para formar un solo entero más grande de 32 bits. Sólo entonces tendrás la IP en un formato adecuado para poder aplicarle la operación `&`.

Por suerte la biblioteca estándar C tiene funciones para manejar IPs y convertirlas de su forma "cadena separada por puntos" a su representación interna en forma de número binario de 32 bits, y viceversa (para imprimir el resultado necesitamos volver a convertirlo de su representación interna binaria de 32 bits a una cadena que tenga separados por puntos los valores de cada byte).

Si no conoces bien la API de sockets el código puede resultar un poco confuso, pero esta es la forma en que podrías hacerlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(){

    char *direccion_ascii;
    char *mascara_ascii;
    direccion_ascii = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    mascara_ascii = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

    printf("Introduce la primera direccion ip: ");
    scanf("%s", direccion_ascii);

    printf("Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: ");
    scanf("%s", mascara_ascii);

    struct sockaddr_in direccion, mascara, resultado;
    direccion.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(direccion_ascii);
    mascara.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(mascara_ascii);

    resultado.sin_addr.s_addr = 
        (direccion.sin_addr.s_addr & mascara.sin_addr.s_addr);
    printf("La nueva direccion es %s\n", 
       inet_ntoa(resultado.sin_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

Y ahora sí funciona bien:

```
Introduce la primera direccion ip: 172.217.0.164
Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: 255.255.0.0
La nueva direccion es 172.217.0.0
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! ... Otra cosa, al tratar de ejecutar el código que implementaste, me dio un error por la librería `#include <arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: @Alvarez Quizás dependa del operativo en que intentas compilar y del compilador usado ¿cuál es? Asumí que era un Linux con gcc

Comment: Estoy usando windows 10

Comment: estoy usando el compilador de Dev-C++

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el include por `winsock2.h`

Comment: Me sale  3 errores, dos veces `programa.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to __imp_inet_addr'` y una vez `programa.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to __imp_inet_ntoa'`

Comment: Tienes que decirle al compilador que enlace con la librería `libwsock32.a`. No sé cómo se hace en Dev-C++ (no lo uso), pero he leido que es desde el menu proyecto/opciones del proyecto, en la pestaña "parametros", añadir biblioteca u objeto.

Comment: Okey, investigare sobre eso, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

> [Error] invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'char *')

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> [Error] Operandos no válidos al operador binario & (tienen 'char *' y 'char *')

Claramente te está diciendo que el operador binario & no puede ser usado sobre operandos que sean punteros a carácter (`char *`). Y así está establecido en el [estándar de C](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 6.5.10 Operador AND a nivel de bits
>
> […]
>
> **Restricciones**
>
> Cada uno de los operandos debe tener tipo integral.

Los punteros no son tipos integrales, pero (<sub>por muy antintuitivo que parezca</sub>) los `char` si lo son. Así que puedes aplicar la máscara carácter a carácter:

```
char direccion[16];
char mascara[16];
char resultado[16];

printf("Introduce la primera direccion ip: ");
scanf("%s", direccion);

printf("Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: ");
scanf("%s", mascara);

for (int i = 0; i != 16; ++i)
    resultado[i] = direccion[i] & mascara[i];
```

Pero esto no es lo que quieres:

> ```
> Introduce la primera direccion ip: 192.168.11.1
> Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: 255.0.0.0
> Resultado: 010.0&0.0
> ```

Eso es hacer el and binario sobre los **caracteres** de los números, no sobre los números. Tiene tanto sentido como rebozar la foto de un muslo de pollo.

El carácter `'1'` tiene valor 49 y el carácter `'2'` tiene valor 50:

[image]

Por lo tanto:

```
0011'0001 49 '1' &
0011'0010 50 '2'
---------
0011'0000 48 '0'
```

La misma operación con el resto de la cadena:

```
                                                             111111
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15|  0123456789012345
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|49|57|50|46|49|54|56|46|49|49|46|49| 0| 0| 0| 0| "192.168.11.1____" &
|50|53|53|46|48|46|48|46|48| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| "255.0.0.0_______"
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|48|49|48|46|48|38|48|46|48| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| "010.0&0.0_______"
```

<sup>Estoy usando el guion bajo (`_`) como carácter nulo</sup>

Queda claro que en realidad no quieres trabajar con cadenas de caracteres si no con valores integrales de 8 bits.

#### Propuesta.

Lee los cuatro componentes de la dirección IP, no la IP como si fuese una cadena, no uses memoria dinámica innecesariamente e inicializa tus variables:

```
unsigned char direccion[4] = "";
unsigned char mascara[4] = "";
unsigned char resultado[4] = "";

printf("Introduce la primera direccion ip: ");
scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &direccion[0], &direccion[1], &direccion[2], &direccion[3]);

printf("Introduce la mascara de dicha direccion: ");
scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &mascara[0], &mascara[1], &mascara[2], &mascara[3]);

for (int i = 0; i != 16; ++i)
    resultado[i] = direccion[i] & mascara[i];
```